# Unwanted oscillations and distortions in buck converter

Tags: oscillator, buck, oscillation, distortion

I've tried today to design a very simple and crude 26V to ~12V buck converter. But after testing it in LTspice I've got some weird and unexplained oscillations and distortions. The oscillations produced on 'Q1E' then distorted the signal of the oscillator.

Here's the picture:[image: pic]

The green oscillations had a frequency of about 21MHz which it then "mirrored" to the base of Q1. Also the frequency of the 'OSC' had decreased from expected 640kHz to 410kHz and the duty cycle has increased.

If I increase L1 to about 100uH the oscillations are gone and the circuit works as expected. The 'OSC' and 'Q1E' frequency then becomes around 640kHz with a 50% duty cycle.

Why does this happen? The LC resonant frequency of L1 and C6 is only around 16kHz. Does L1 form a resonant circuit with some other capacitor (Q1-BE,D4)?

Is there a way to get rid of the oscillations without increasing L1 to much? I could add a resistor between 'Q1E' and L1 but that would defeat the whole purpose of buck converter.

Comment: Um, why are you using an LM393 instead of a proper PWM controller? And why would you arbitrarily change the inductor size, knowing how crucial it is in the overall operation of the buck? If you're just tinkering to learn about bucks, may I suggest that you grab a [PWM switch model](http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm) from this site and then experiment with frequency, inductance and capacitance? The PWM switch model abstracts out the messy bits of the control and allows you to understand the dynamics of how the converter works without designing a full-blown controller.

Comment: The green oscillations exist mainly because you have an asynchronous buck converter operating in DCM, and these oscillations happen when the inductor current reaches zero. If you increase the inductance, you push the operation into CCM for a given output current. The oscillations exist because of the parasitic capacitances (diode, switching transistor, PCB traces).

Comment: @AdamLawrence As I've said, I am only interested in making a really crude ~12V power supply and I had LM393 handy. I changed the size becuase I just wanted to know where the problem lies. Also this converter is just gonna be a very simple with only ON/OFF oscillator.

Comment: @LaszloValko Thanks, I've confirmed it in LTspice. Could you write this as an anwser so I could accept. And explain why does the oscillations occur when L1 current goes to 0A and not when it doesnt. Thanks!

Comment: @LaszloValko Yes, please, do write a complete answer with some details regarding the consequences of DCM/CCM. I never quite understood the implications of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the inductor is resonating not with the filter capacitor but with the parasitic capacitances in the transistor and the diode, it could also be that the ringing is being fed back into the LM393 through R10, you mentioned that the ringing was on the base as well? (the output resistance of those things isn't that great). What happens if you use a second 393 as a buffer between U3 and Q1?